# Последовательный порт для приложения Android на Unity

Tags: android, unity3d, serialport

Я пытаюсь реализовать подключение последовательного порта в приложении Unity для Android устройств.

1. Как я понимаю библиотека .NET IO.SerialPort для таких целей не подходит. Т.к. она не может запуститься на Android.
2. Никаких бесплатных или открытых решений по серийному порту для Unity я не нашел
3. Я написал минимальный код для работы последовательного порта на java и создал AAR, который смог подключить к ОСНОВНОМУ потоку Unity. Но работать с портом в основном потоке...
4. Я пробовал в лоб вынести всю логику связанную с подключением библиотеки AAR в параллельный поток. Все работает, НО метод, который вызывает из JAVA код UNITY и передает данные, которые пришли с серийного порта, не доходят до приложения.

`UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("UnityClass", "UnityMethod", "Data");`

это работает в основном потоке Unity, НО метод не вызывается, если он находится в параллельном потоке..

Собственно вопрос. Как правильно и удобно было бы реализовать передачу данных, которые приходят на серийный порт, которые получает AAR, и которые он должен передать в Unity код

Comment: `RS-232` порт, земля ему пухом... На Android устройстве, видимо самодельном франкенштейне... Да еще и используемый каким-то образом в видеоигре на Unity... К доктору ходили? Не помогло?

Comment: @Yaroslav, большое спасибо, ваш комментарий, нереально полезен